# .NET Maui Collectionview Lack on Android Platforme

Tags: .net, maui, collectionview

I developed an application with . NET Maui and I am stuck on the slow loading of recordings on a collectionview that is on the Android platform to display 100 recordings it takes 5 minutes and sometimes 10 minutes. and also the scroll is too slow to react, I don’t know if that is a bug of .NET Maui, because on xamarin forms there is no such problem.

Any sugestion please

currently I am trying to develop the application using kotlin under android

Comment: there is no info in this post we could use to help you.  Please read [ask] before posting

Comment: My suggestion is that you put the XAML, and all the relevant code behind it, in your question. CollectionView runs well on android, if you do not misuse it. Also about that non-sense of "kotlin under android". What does this has to do with MAUI?